# how to add users to open ldap installed on windows

Tags: openldap

Is openldap meant for only Linux machines? Can we set up ope ldap on Linux machine and access it on windows machine? I have installed open ldap on windows but don't know how to add users  or see values.

Answer (score 0):

1. No, there are Windows ports. See for example www.userbooster.de. But you already know that, as you've already installed it, so why are you asking?
2. Of course. Again I don't know why you're even asking.
3. This is documented: see ldapadd, ldapsearch, etc.

Your questions seem fairly pointless to me, and asking them here ditto.

Comment: i installed the windows version downloaded --the userbooster tool. Thanks for the info.http://jtechspace.blogspot.in/2012/06/working-with-open-ldap-jaas-and-jboss.html.

Answer (score 0):

> Given three links may help you **:**

1) To install ldap : https://www.userbooster.de/en/support/feature-articles/openldap-for-windows-installation.aspx

2) To add users or ldif file : http://www.kukusan-network.blogspot.in/2012/01/how-to-setting-ldap-openldap-in-windows.html

3) To explore ldap directory : http://ldaptool.sourceforge.net/

Answer (score -1):

look at

http://www.zytrax.com/books/ldap/ch5/index.html#step1-ldif

you need basically can use ldapmodify with the -a param and construct your ldif file with the right changeType: add/modify

see here:

http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19199-01/816-6400-10/lmodify.html